# How do I start my Java program with more than one java agent?

Tags: jvm, javaagents

I'm aware of how to start a java progam with a java agent:

```
java -javaagent:myAgent.jar MyJavaProgram
```

But what if I want to add 2 or more java agents to instrument my program? I do not want to reinvoke the java -javaagent:... for every agent I have to load in JVM.

I've tried something like this :

```
java -javaagent:agentA.jar, agentB.jar MyJavaProgram
```

or something like this:

```
java -javaagent:agentA.jar agentB.jar MyJavaProgram
```

But have no success.

Is there an answer to solve my problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

How about two `javaagent` parameters?

```
java -javaagent:agentA.jar -javaagent:agentB.jar MyJavaProgram
```

Answer (score 64):

It would appear you can do this by using multiple arguments. From the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html):

> On implementations with a command-line interface, an agent is started by adding this option to the command-line:
>
> ```
> -javaagent:jarpath[=options]
> ```
>
> *jarpath* is the path to the agent JAR file. *options* is the agent options. **This switch may be used multiple times on the same command-line, thus creating multiple agents**. More than one agent may use the same jarpath. An agent JAR file must conform to the JAR file specification.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answers, if you are using ant and want to include `<jvmargs />` with more than one jar to `-javaagent` to start the server, here's how I did it,

**build.xml**

```
<target name="blah">
...
    <jvmarg value="-javaagent:${jar1.path}" />
    <jvmarg value="-javaagent:${jar2.path}" />
...
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project with the goal to support multiple Java agents. Currently it is limited to specific ones.

> Agent Bond is a super agent, which wraps and dispatches on several other agents. That way, you only have to install a single agent within your JVM with a single set of configuration data (which contains multiple separate parts).

See https://github.com/fabric8io/agent-bond/blob/master/README.md for details